# Вызов метода telegram python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Пишу парсер каналов на `python`.
Так как `aiogram` в принципе не особо приспособлен под такие цели, а `telethon` говорит о недостатке прав при вызове метода [channels.getMessages](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getMessages) появился резон писать на `pure requests`.

Но не особо понятно почему при вызове `https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/channels.getMessages` возвращается 404.

Хотя пробовал и `get args` передавать, и `post data`. Результат один.

Comment: этот метод не для бота

Comment: @Violet, Но ведь `Bot can use this method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, что можно сделать через BOT API уже есть в `aiogram`.

Проблема в другом. Ваша задача через `Telegram BOT API` не решается.

Используйте `пользовательский API`, а не API для ботов.

Используйте документацию Telethon для входа из под пользователя:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html